# Virtual property readonly - unable to change its value

Tags: c#, properties, readonly, episerver

I'm trying to dynamically assign a value from DB to a property which inherits from EpiServer PageData class. Here is what I mean:

```
namespace Episerver9.Models.Pages
{
    [ContentType]
    public class StartPage : PageData
    {
        public virtual string Username { get; set; }
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

        [ReadOnly(false)]
        [Editable(true)]
        public virtual string testfield { get; set; }


    }
}
```

And in controller I'm trying the following:

```
namespace Episerver9.Controllers
{
    public class StartPageController : PageController<StartPage>
    {
        // GET: StartPage

        public ActionResult Index(StartPage currentPage)
        {
            currentPage.testfield = "test";
            return View(currentPage);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to display in the view:

```
@Html.PropertyFor(x=>x.testfield)
// Trying to dynamically populate the data from code, later on from DB
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Additional information: The property testfield is read-only
```

This happens even tho I clearly specified for the property that IT IS NOT read only... Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because **ContentData** objects are always read-only for performance purposes. To change any properties, you have to create a *writable clone* like:

```
currentPage.CreateWritableClone()
```

That will give you an instance of your page that you can change, for example to save changes using an **IContentRepository** instance.

However, note that these instances are read-only for a reason. :) You're better off creating a separate view model that you pass to your view.

Comment: Hey @TedNyberg I've did some research on Episerver, and most tutorials shown just handling the static part of the HTML. None of them shown how to dynamically manage content from DB using Episerver... Or perhaps that's not its purpose? Could you summarize it in few sentences so that I can understand better? Or perhaps do u have some useful links where I could read about it... I've went through their user manual already...

Comment: I believe world.episerver.com is your best bet, it contains loads of useful info!